# What is the syntactic function of the phrase 'in a tribe' (and it's constituents) in the sentence 'We live in a tribe.'?

Tags: syntax, parsing

Also, would it be the same if we say 'We live in a city.' or 'We live in a society.'?

What kind of verb is live here?

Comment: What research have you done so far? Do you understand how things like prepositional phrases and nominal (or noun) phrases are constructed? If so, what exactly is unclear to you about "in a tribe"?

Answer (score 1):

"Live" is an ordinary active, present-tense verb.  "We live in a society", but, for example, a hermit does not live in a society.